# Pandas Drop Duplicates To CSV

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/home/test/cities.csv')

dupes = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['latitude', 'longitude'], keep=False)

dupes.to_csv('/home/test/results.csv')
```

I want to drop all records with duplicate latitude and longitude information.

The output CSV file contains all the non-duplicated records.

Any suggestions on how to extract all the duplicate records?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### [**`duplicated`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html)

The sister method to [**`drop_duplicates`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

```
these_are_the_dupes = df[df.duplicated(subset=['latitude', 'longitude'], keep=False)]
```